# Only join when there are no children?

Tags: mysql

I want to select a parent based on two conditions: if the parent has an active child or no child at all. The following covers the first:

```
SELECT p.* FROM parents p, children c 
WHERE p.status = 'active' 
AND c.parent_id = p.id AND c.status = 'active' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

How do I add the second condition?

Comment: Read up on `LEFT JOIN`s.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT p.* FROM parents p
LEFT JOIN children c
ON children.parent_id = parent.id and children.status <> 'active' 
WHERE parent.status = 'active' AND children.parent_id is null
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM parents p, children c 
WHERE p.status = 'active' 
AND c.parent_id = p.id AND c.status = 'active' 
union
SELECT p.* 
FROM parents p
where p.id not in (select distinct c.parent_id from children)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM parents
LEFT JOIN children 
ON children.parent_id = parent.id AND children.status = 'active' 
WHERE parent.status = 'active'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I think the children check must be in the `WHERE` in order the join to cover the mentionned choices.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN children 
ON children.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE parent.status = 'active' AND (children.status = 'active' OR children.status IS NULL)` resp. `LEFT JOIN children 
ON children.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE parent.status = 'active' AND COALESCE(children.status, 'active') = 'active'`

Comment: This will return parents with inactive children (since the join condition will ensure that such parents are included in the select with null-valued children columns).